# How can get RawSignalStrength of a bledevice which already conneceted with my computer in uwp?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

How can get RawSignalStrength of a bledevice which already conneceted with my computer?
I can get SignalStrength of a bledevice when I does not connect with it.  after I connected it , How can get RawSignalStrength of a it in a uwp app?

Comment: IDeviceInformation. read AEP property named: "System.Devices.Aep.SignalStrength". However, once device connected the RSSI value will not be updated.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko  I already tried this, it not only not updated,  but also it does contain this System.Devices.Aep.SignalStrength key in its dictionary.

Comment: It 100% contains the key. Looks like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I use foreach list the ble device's DeviceInformation.Properties dictionary, but did not find this.

Comment: I need the realtime rssi.

Comment: You must not use for each and just simple use Lookup method. About real time RSSI it is better to ask from Microsoft, not here.

Comment: Windows community tool kit BluetoothLEHelper contains  [RSSI](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Connectivity/BluetoothLEHelper/ObservableBluetoothLEDevice.cs#L337) property, have you tired that?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT  thanks, it seems useless.  I saw the soure code of BluetoothLEHelper , and ObservableBluetoothLEDevice in the Windows community tool kit. it still bases on winrt BluetoothLEDevice class, which does not provide realtime rssi.

Comment: Why not use timer to report rssi for real time?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT  thanks,how to get real time rssi by timer?  I try to use the BluetoothLEHelper, it always report rssi is "0";

Comment: You could make [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-20348) to get rssi for each second, and if the rssi vale is always zero  [`System.Devices.Aep.SignalStrength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties#associationendpoint-properties)property may not support for current protocol